# Trac_IK plugin for MoveIt group relies on deprecated API

Tags: ros, moveit, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a neat way to handle this warning while using Trac-IK solver with MoveIt Assistant?

`IK plugin for group 'right_arm' relies on deprecated API. Please implement initialize(RobotModel, ...).`

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391138/trac_ik-plugin-for-moveit-group-relies-on-deprecated-api./) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trac-IK should simply implement the newer API. Apparently they did not do that. If they don't want to use the functionality this is quickly done because `RobotModel::getURDF()` can just give you the description needed for the old API, but they can likely safe some time by just using the RobotModel MoveIt prepared for them.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2021-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-11-18**:
@v4hn, thanks for your answer, where can I add `RobotModel::getURDF()`, to which part of the trac_ik code so it works properly? can you please tell me, thanks in advance.